# pynput is installed with pip, but `import pynput` in PyCharm can't find it

Tags: python, pycharm, installation-package

I installed the pynput Python package with pip. I got this error in PyCharm when trying to import pynput with `import pynput`.

```
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\keyloger.py\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/User/Desktop/hello world.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/hello world.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pynput
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]

Even though pynput is installed, `import pynput` in PyCharm can't find it.

Comment: i dont know why i got a dislike im just asking a question it's my first time using python  so please bare with me it would really help me if some one can just answer my question

Comment: instead of disliking my post tell me what can i do to improve the question or to improve the code i thought this forum is for helping people, i got experience in coding just not in python so please at least constructive criticism would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, PyCharm uses pip to manage project packages. To manage Python packages for the project interpreter, select the Project Interpreter page in the project **Settings/Preferences** or select **Interpreter Settings** in the Python Interpreter widget.

Select *File* -> *Settings* -> *Project:* project_name -> *Project Interpreter*. Click the **+** button which is marked by the mouse cursor in the screenshot to install Python packages in the selected project.

[image: project Settings]

Search for any Python package. Select it and click the *Install Package* button in the lower left corner of the Available Packages window to install it. PyCharm will automatically choose the package version for you or you can check the checkbox to the left of *Specify version* and select the package version from the *Specify version* dropdown menu.

As you can see in the above screenshot pynput is not in the list of available packages, so you need to follow the instructions after the 2nd screenshot to use the pynput package that you already installed with pip instead of reinstalling pynput in PyCharm.

[image: install Flask]

Whenever you [install a Python package](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) specifically for a project, PyCharm adds the packages that were installed to the project's venv directory where PyCharm will find them automatically.

PyCharm does not automatically find your globally installed Python packages unless the project has been configured to find them. To do this select the *Inherit global-site packages* option when you create a new project.

Select *File* -> *New Project* to create a new project. Click the triangle marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot to show the new project's options.

[image]

Then check the *Inherit global-site packages* checkbox and click the  <kbd>Create</kbd>  button in the lower right corner of the Create Project window.

[image]